# Linked-List program, uncertain of ouput/function

Tags: recursion, linked-list

I am wanting to run this with input of a linked-list of 1,2,3,4,5. I am wanting to know both the output of funcA with the above linked-list as well as what the program is actually doing. I believe that it is either reversing the order of the linked list or it is rotating all the items in the linked-list, like 2,3,4,5,1 is this correct? Thank you for any help!

```
   struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *next;};

Node* funcA(Node* in) {
    Node *out = in;
    while (out->next != nullptr) {
    out = out->next;
    }
    funcB(in)->next = NULL;
    return out;
}

Node* funcB(Node* in) {
   if (in->next != nullptr) {
    funcB(in->next)->next = in;
   }
   return in;
}
```

Comment: @EmilTerman `funcB()` doesn't make the given list circular. It makes the next node to point to its previous node, so temporarily they both point to each other, true. But that's not the end - on next iteration the circle will break, until only the first and last node point to each other. But then `funcA()` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand `funcA()` we need to understand `funcB()` first.

### `funcB`

Simply reverses a list and returns the tail of the reversed list (or the head of the original list).
It's doing it by calling itself (recursion) until it reaches the tail of the original list. Then, the recursion starting to fold up and reassigning the `next` pointer of each node to point to the node before it.

### `funcA`

The while loop's goal is to save a pointer `out` to the tail of the input list. So the current state is:

```
List: 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> NULL
      ^                       ^
      in                     out
```

Then, it's calling `funcB` with the head of the list as the argument. We know that `funcB` will reverse its given list and will return its last element. so after `funcB(in)` we'll get:

```
List: 1 <--> 2 <-- 3 <-- 4 <-- 5
      ^                        ^
      in                      out
```

and the return value is the node `1`. So after `funcB(in)->next = NULL`, we'll get:

```
List: NULL <-- 1 <-- 2 <-- 3 <-- 4 <-- 5
               ^                       ^
               in                     out
```

Then, `out` is returned. So overall - `funcA` is taking a linked list, reversing it and returns a pointer to the head of the reversed list `5`.

---

When it comes to linked lists (and pointers in general), the best way to understand is using a pencil and paper - just draw on a paper every state of the list and additional pointers, step by step, until it's clear.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful!